# How do you configure collection view list cells to look inset with rounded corners?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In the Health app, it appears that cells and not sections are styled in this way:

[image]

The closest I know of to getting to this appearance is setting the section to be inset grouped

```
    let listConfiguration = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
    let listLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: listConfiguration)
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = listLayout
```

but I'm not sure of a good approach to giving each cell this appearance like in the screenshot above. I'm assuming the list style collection view shown is two sections with three total cells, rather than three inset grouped sections.

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't know where the cells are. You only know where the white rounded rects are. The cell boundaries could be touching. The visible drawn white materials within each cell are not.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines into your collection view cell (separate cell design).swift file

it will help in adding the border and radius you can customise as required

```
  override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            
            self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            self.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

In SwiftUI, I know you can do this:

```
List(.....) { item in 
    Text("What ever you want here").background(Color.white.cornerRadius(10))
}
```

Add `.cornerRadius` to each of the items or its background
Not sure in `UIKit`
Use `UIHostingView`(or sth like that) to bridge?